# Update jsonb field in PostgreSQL with json that contains single quote

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, jsonb

I'm using PostgreSQL v9.4.12 and I'm trying to update a jsonb column. I want to update the whole json object and not a specific key of the object.

I'm using a Python `dict` to store my object and before using it I'm using `json.dumps()` to transform it to a json formatted String.
However, a value of the json is having a single quote `'` that throws an `psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error` while trying to update.

So far, I've tried:

```
"UPDATE table "
"SET jsonb_column='{} ".format(json.dumps(new_data)) + ""
"WHERE id='12345'"
```

Note that `new_data` is my dict and `jsonb_column` is the name of the column holding the json data.

The error I'm getting:

> psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "s"
>
> LINE 1: ...code": "BR3", "short_description": "This property's price
>   is...
>
> ```
>                                                   ^
> ```

I was assuming that `json.dumps()` escapes the single quote but doesn't seem that to be the case. Is there any solution to overcome this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: jsonb?.. 9.3?.. sure?

Comment: Oops! It's 9.4.12 that I'm using.

Comment: The '{}' inside the string is the Simple Positional Formatting https://pyformat.info/

Comment: hm - never saw it - only c-style `%s`. I don't code with python much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

json is very fine with single quote, eg:

```
t=# select $${"short_description": "This property's price is..."}$$::jsonb;
                        jsonb
------------------------------------------------------
 {"short_description": "This property's price is..."}
(1 row)
```

so I assume you could try using dollar sign quotes, to avoid statement structuring exception with single quotes

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I needed. It worked.

Answer (score 3):

The practice of string concatenation is not a good practice.

Better use the way [documented in PsyCoPg2 docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries).

```
cur.execute("UPDATE table SET jsonb_column = %s WHERE id = %s", [json, id])
```